# Getting arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc: Command not found

Tags: gcc, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3, buildroot

I am trying to build Linux for my Raspberry Pi 3.

When I do `make`, I get the below error.

```
make[2]: /home/rohit/workplace/rp/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc: Command not found
```

A little background will help. I am following this [link](http://lamothe-elec.com/index.php/raspberry/2-rasberry-pi-buildroot-eng) . To summarize this is what I ran.

```
make raspberrypi3_defconfig
make linux-menuconfig
make
```

From the error I get that the cross gcc is not available at the path as it should be. But I am not sure what I am missing.

The complete log of the `make` is pasted [here](http://pastebin.com/bd79eQ4r). The `output/host/usr/bin` folder also doesn't contain `arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc`, though it does contain `arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc`. I have pasted the contents of the folder [here](http://pastebin.com/xCQRdir7).

Please help.

Comment: You provide way too litlle information to be of any use. You should at least give a little more context for the error: which package was being built? It's also best to post the entire log (in a pastebin), Also say which buildroot version and which distro you are using. Can you check if the path arm-buildroot-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc exists? Does the corresponding .br_real file exist? Can you run 'file' and 'ldd' on them? Please edit your question with these answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i was having this problem and after a `make clean` the problem was solved. I think the error was because different toolchains used in different builds. The [manual](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#full-rebuild) says that is one of the cases that you have to do a `make clean`